# Rename files before uploading to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, paperclip, aws-sdk

I've got my rails application saving to AWS S3 the upload files that a user has selected. The users fills in a couple fields on the form relating to the file that they are about to upload.  I need to use that information to construct the new file name.

This is the model:

```
class DocAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :doc_attachment_type
  belongs_to :language

  has_attached_file :attachment

  before_save :rename_file

  #Attempted Paperclips callbacks but couldn't get values for the form
  #after_attachment_post_process :rename_file

  validates_attachment_presence :attachment

  validates_attachment_content_type :attachment,
                                content_type: %w(application/pdf application/vnd.ms-excel application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet application/msword application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document text/plain),
                                size: { :in => 0..10.megabytes }

  validates :doc_attachment_type_id, presence: true
  validates :code, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :language_id, presence: true

  def rename_file
    extension = File.extname(attachment_file_name).gsub(/^\.+/, '')
    filename = attachment_file_name.gsub(/\.#{extension}$/, '')
    new_attachment_file_name = "#{self.code}-#{self.language.name}.#{extension}"

    attachment.instance_write(:attachment_file_name, new_attachment_file_name)

  end
end
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
gem 'paperclip'
```

I tried to use paperclips before/after callbacks but they didn't appear to provide me with the submitted form fields data. I like the idea of s3_direct_upload gem but I'm not sure if it will work because it doesnt appear to be in active development

Any help greatly appreciated.

Longer term i would like to Allow the user to do multiple uploads using AJAX with some kind of progress bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues was with the last line of the rename_file method.

```
def rename_file
  extension = File.extname(attachment_file_name).gsub(/^\.+/, '')
  filename = attachment_file_name.gsub(/\.#{extension}$/, '')
  new_attachment_file_name = "#{self.code}-#{self.language.name}.#{extension}"

  attachment.instance_write(:file_name, new_attachment_file_name)
end
```